# ¿Como solucionar error "No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor"?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

estoy implementando json en mi proyecto y al momento de hacer pruebas en la consola obtengo el siguiente Error:

No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.montalban.demo.models.entity.Juego["categoria"]->com.montalban.demo.models.entity.Categoria$HibernateProxy$Acrozsuk["hibernateLazyInitializer"])

Class Persona

```
package com.montalban.demo.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;



@Entity
@Table(name = "productora")
public class Productora implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_productora")
    private Long idProductora;
    private String nombre;
    private String pais;
    private String fundacion;
    
    @Column(name = "fecha_registro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date fechaRegistro;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productora", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Juego> juegos;
    

    
    public void addJuego(Juego juegos) {
        this.juegos.add(juegos);
    }
    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        fechaRegistro = new Date();
    }

    public Long getIdProductora() {
        return idProductora;
    }

    public void setIdProductora(Long idProductora) {
        this.idProductora = idProductora;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public String getFundacion() {
        return fundacion;
    }

    public void setFundacion(String fundacion) {
        this.fundacion = fundacion;
    }

    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return fechaRegistro;
    }

    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }

    public List<Juego> getJuegos() {
        return juegos;
    }

    public void setJuegos(List<Juego> juegos) {
        this.juegos = juegos;
    }

}
```

Class Juego

```
package com.montalban.demo.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;



@Entity
@Table(name = "juego")
public class Juego implements Serializable  {
    
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_juego")
    private Long idJuego;
    
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name ="fecha_lanzamiento")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date fechaLanzamiento;
    
    private String idioma;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_categoria")
    private Categoria categoria;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_consola")
    private Consola consola;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_productora")
    private Productora productora;
    
    @Column(name ="fecha_registro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date fechaRegistro;


    
    public Long getIdJuego() {
        return idJuego;
    }


    public void setIdJuego(Long idJuego) {
        this.idJuego = idJuego;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public Date getFechaLanzamiento() {
        return fechaLanzamiento;
    }


    public void setFechaLanzamiento(Date fechaLanzamiento) {
        this.fechaLanzamiento = fechaLanzamiento;
    }


    public String getIdioma() {
        return idioma;
    }


    public void setIdioma(String idioma) {
        this.idioma = idioma;
    }


    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }


    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }


    public Consola getConsola() {
        return consola;
    }


    public void setConsola(Consola consola) {
        this.consola = consola;
    }


    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return fechaRegistro;
    }


    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }


    public Productora getProductora() {
        return productora;
    }


    public void setProductora(Productora productora) {
        this.productora = productora;
    }


}
```

Class Categoria

```
package com.montalban.demo.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_categoria")
    private Long idCategoria;
    
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name ="fecha_registro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date fechaRegistro;
    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        fechaRegistro = new Date();
    }

    public Long getIdCategoria() {
        return idCategoria;
    }

    public void setIdCategoria(Long idCategoria) {
        this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return fechaRegistro;
    }

    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }
    
    

}
```

les agradecería si me podrían ayudar con este error.

Comment: podrias mostrarnos donde instancias dichas clases para poder ayudarte. Estoy seguro que el problema está ahi.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_categoria")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
 private Categoria categoria;
```

El juego tiene categoría, pero la categoría no tiene sentido que tenga juego y está bien, pero hay que agregarle `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` en la clase `Juego`

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un proyecto y me salio el mismo error no habia visto la solución, pero es colocarle esta anotación en la clase model y listo.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```